# I can hear sound only through headphones

Tags: sound, headphones, soundcard, kodi

I have installed Photoshop and Kodi on a fresh Ubuntu installation on my HP laptop today.

Everything worked fine before installing Kodi. Then I realized that I coudn't hear anything. I checked for the sound settings and it showed my built-in speakers. I then played a random video on Youtube and still heard no sound. I could finally hear something as I plugged in my headphones.

Is this a software or hardware problem? How do I fix it?

Comment: Don't add "solved" to the title. Write an answer and accept 24 hours later.

Comment: wrt https://askubuntu.com/revisions/703528/3 , problem solved by itself

Comment: Its not off-topic, i read about others having this problem, and it is a software problem, that happens when i suspend